# Как с помощью ejs создать многоуровневое меню?

Tags: javascript, вёрстка, шаблонизаторы, ejs

Допустим нужно сделать 3х уровневое меню для магазина.
Подскажите, как сделать массив пунктов и подпунктов 3х уровневого меню?
что-то наподобии:

```
var catalog = [ 
    {id: 0, title: 'item1', parent_id: 0},
    {id  1, title: 'item2', parent_id: 0},
    {id  2, title: 'item3', parent_id: 1},
    {id  3, title: 'item4', parent_id: 1},
 ...
]
```

Подскажите, как потом из этого массива формировать меню, т.е. в цикле нужно перебирать этот массив, и формировать li, с текстом из массива.

Comment: что посоветуете с кодом?